# Looking for dual-CPU capable motherboard that is compatible with 2 Intel Celeron G1840 processors?

Tags: processor, motherboard

Looking to build a value-gaming PC, and it seems like Celeron processors are very cheap for the performance they provide.

I am okay with server motherboards, no preference.
Any additional recommendations (if such a setup is possible, anyway) about RAM and I/O ports (USB 3.0 and USB 3.1, Thunderbolt, ethernet) are appreciated.  Suggestions or recommendations about dedicated graphics cards, PCIe/NVMe, SSDs, power supply units - basically anything you can buy and attach to a compatible motherboard - are fine.

But most importantly - is such a setup compatible?

If there is no such compatibility, are there other value processors from Intel that I should look at to accomplish the same task?  Thanks!

Comment: a) Please Note: I highly doubt a _Celeron_ will be suitable for gaming, they have a "worse" architecture compared to Intel Core is, they lack quite a few instruction set features and they are clocked rather low (the G1840 is fixed at 2.8GHz) b) The Celeron G1840 doesn't support dual CPU configurations.

Comment: Okay, then how about the Pentiums?  Do those support dual-CPU configuration?

Comment: no, even Server Pentiums don't support dual-CPU configurations. AFAICT the Xeon E5s and Xeon E7s are the only (Intel) CPUs to support dual-CPU usage and they cost at least 200 USD a piece

Comment: Specifically, if you want dual CPUs, you're looking for a Xeon where the model number begins with a "2", "4", or "8".  Some of the lower-end E5s don't support dual-socket operation.

Answer (score 1):

They probably don't exist. Nearly *all* dual processor systems are xeon e5s or e7s using sockets like LGA2011 or LGA1567. Your pentiums use LGA 115x sockets. Since many chipset functions are rolled into the processor, you can't even get a chipset that would work here.

The only 'consumer' dual processor boards intel has made are s[kull trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Skulltrail), in 2008 and used a special processor that was using the same socket as contemporary xeons.

In short, there's no low cost, dual socket board. You might just choose to use the budget on a more powerful single socket either with more cores, or better clock speed.

Answer (score 0):

Xeon and Opteron processors are the ONLY modern x86 processors on the market capable of running in tandem. All other CPU brands (Celeron, Pentium, Core iX, Sempron, Athlon, FX, AX) are incapable of running on tandem motherboards.

That being said, it would not be unreasonable to make an entry-level gaming PC based on the G1840 CPU. Because you are looking at the absolute cheapest CPU available on a modern socket, I am going to assume extreme budget constraint - you could do something like this, using SteamOS or Linux as your OS to get started with gaming:

- CPU: Intel Celeron G1840 2.8GHz Dual-Core Processor  ($39.99 @ SuperBiiz)
- Motherboard: Biostar B85MG Micro ATX LGA1150 Motherboard ($47.98 @ Newegg)
- Memory: PNY Anarchy 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory ($23.98 @ Newegg)
- Storage: Western Digital Caviar Blue 250GB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive ($22.25 @ Amazon)
- Video Card: Zotac GeForce GTX 750 Ti 2GB Video Card  ($99.99 @ Newegg)
- Case: DIYPC M89-R MicroATX Mini Tower Case  ($23.99 @ Newegg)
- Power Supply: Raidmax 380W ATX Power Supply  ($19.99 @ SuperBiiz)  Total: $278.17

Alternatively, you might consider looking into an AMD APU option, as most of their A6, A8, and A10 desktop processors are vastly more powerful than the Celeron G1840, and come with integrated graphics that are actually useful for light gaming. For example, the A8-7600 is much faster than this Celeron on average, yet it also features an integrated GPU capable of comfortably handling games like CS:GO, League of Legends, or most Rocket League at high settings and framerates at 1080p.